# Find Subscriberkey based on Subscriber ID

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I have a daily file with only Subscriber IDs sent from Audience Studio into Salesforce Marketing Cloud. I have imported the file into a data extension called 'SubscriberID'. I will need to find the corresponding Subscriberkeys for these Subscriber IDs (from the _Subsrcibers table) and ingest them into a Data Extension called 'ABCD'.

trying this query with no errors in Automation Studio but it's not working :

```
select 
c.subscriberid
c.EmailAddress
s.Subscriberid
from [SubscriberID] s 
left join _Subscribers c  on (s.subscriberid = c.subscriberid)
```

Comment: You are pulling subscriberid twice and do not reference SubscriberKey at all. Is this a typo from copy paste?

Answer (score 2):

SubscriberID and SubscriberKey are both found in the [_Subscribers](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_subscribers.htm&type=5) data view.
Ensure the field names and datatypes match, and try updating your query to the following:

```
SELECT
  s.subscriberid 
  ,c.SubscriberKey
FROM [SubscriberID] s
LEFT JOIN _Subscribers c ON c.SubscriberID = s.subscriberid
```

Note that depending on your Business Unit Structure, you may need to change the _Subscribers table to be ent._Subscribers.